# How can I get hidden properties in Excel that are passed with XMLHTTP requests such as userid?

Tags: excel, vba, rest, authentication, xmlhttprequest

I have an excel workbook that interacts with a webservice that has authentication. The first time I make a webservice request using VBA with XMLHTTP I have to enter my userid and password in a pop-up box from the webservice. Excel remember's the userid and password for each successive xml request that I make up until I close the Excel application. The REST webservice's authentication tool is stateless so I'm not keeping a connection. I have a need to capture the userid entered by the user to use it in the webservices URL for a GET request. Is there a way to capture the user's userid from Excel using VBA so that I don't have the prompt the user twice for the same information?

**Katz**, Thank you for the response. I am familiar with these functions. My scenario is different in that I am interacting with an external secure webservice that requires a different userid than my windows domain. In my case the webservice is stateless and each time I call it, it requires the userid/password unique to the service. When sending requests to this webservice through Excel using VBA, Excel somehow remembers the userid and password and as long as I don't close the instance of Excel, I do not need have to enter the userid/password interactively. I need to be able to extract just the userid from where ever Excel is sourcing this information so that I can place it in the GET request as userid can be used in the GET request as filtering criteria for the response from the webservice.

This userid has to be stored somewhere in excel or in the system enviroment to be reused when subsequent GET requests are sent to this webservice in order to suppress the logon window after the first request. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a local file you can read the computername and username with this code:

```
Set WSHnet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    UserName = WSHnet.UserName
    UserDomain = WSHnet.UserDomain
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & UserDomain & "/" & UserName & ",user")
    userfullname = objUser.FullName
Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = Environ("COMPUTERNAME") & ", " & userfullname
```

maybe it works for you also in your online file